# Finding nearest time point with conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse

Suppose I have this dataset

```
jar_camp    jar campaign    start_date.time      end_date.time
1_pf1.1     1   pf1.1       2019-01-05 10:34:00  2019-01-05 10:41:00
2_pf1.1     2   pf1.1       2019-01-05 10:52:34  2019-01-05 11:03:00
3_pf1.1     3   pf1.1       2019-01-05 11:11:42  2019-01-05 11:21:00
1_pf2.1     1   pf2.1       2019-01-09 10:29:19  2019-01-09 10:39:35
2_pf2.1     2   pf2.1       2019-01-09 10:42:15  2019-01-09 10:53:10
3_pf2.1     3   pf2.1       2019-01-09 10:58:35  2019-01-09 11:10:40
1_pf3.1     1   pf3.1       2019-01-15 10:11:52  2019-01-15 10:22:38
2_pf3.1     2   pf3.1       2019-01-15 10:27:38  2019-01-15 10:38:56
3_pf3.1     3   pf3.1       2019-01-15 10:42:02  2019-01-15 10:52:41
1_pf4.1     1   pf4.1       2019-01-22 09:06:29  2019-01-22 09:17:05
2_pf4.1     2   pf4.1       2019-01-22 09:21:22  2019-01-22 09:31:56
3_pf4.1     3   pf4.1       2019-01-22 09:35:00  2019-01-22 09:47:26
1_pf5.1     2   pf5.1       2019-01-29 10:48:45  2019-01-29 10:59:09
2_pf5.1     3   pf5.1       2019-01-29 11:04:44  2019-01-29 11:18:24
20_pf5.1    1   pf5.1       2019-01-29 15:05:47  2019-01-29 15:16:50
1_pf8.1     1   pf8.1       2019-03-12 08:57:45  2019-03-12 09:07:55
2_pf8.1     2   pf8.1       2019-03-12 09:12:23  2019-03-12 09:22:50
3_pf8.1     3   pf8.1       2019-03-12 09:25:58  2019-03-12 09:36:29
1_pf9.1     1   pf9.1       2019-03-27 08:11:11  2019-03-27 08:21:31
2_pf9.1     2   pf9.1       2019-03-27 08:23:16  2019-03-27 08:33:55
3_pf9.1     3   pf9.1       2019-03-27 08:35:22  2019-03-27 08:46:13


structure                                                                            
   (list(jar_camp = c("1_pf2.1", "2_pf2.1", "3_pf2.1", "1_pf3.1", "2_pf3.1", "3_pf3.1", "1_pf4.1", "2_pf4.1", "3_pf4.1"), 
jar = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), campaign = c("pf2.1","pf2.1", "pf2.1", "pf3.1", "pf3.1", "pf3.1", "pf4.1", "pf4.1","pf4.1"), 
start_date.time = structure(c(1547029759, 1547030535,1547031515, 1547547112, 1547548058, 1547548922, 1548147989, 1548148882, 1548149700), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    end_date.time = structure(c(1547030375, 1547031190, 1547032240, 
    1547547758, 1547548736, 1547549561, 1548148625, 1548149516, 
    1548150446), 
class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001a324ab1ef0>, sorted = "stamp", class = "data.frame")
```

and I for each "jar" (except for "campaign"=pf1.1) want to calculate the difference between the "start_date.time" and the nearest "end_date.time" that is < than the "start_data.time". How would I do that? I'm a newbie and primarily use tidyverse.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you dput your data?

Comment: Hi Sergio, I googled dput and edited my question according to what I think it is you're asking. Cheers

Comment: Thanks. It's still not 100% clear to me what you need. Do you need only to subtract the difference between end_date.time and start_date.time, for each jar and each campaing? Can you give me an example of what the expected output is, maybe for a single jar?

Comment: Thanks for helping out! I guess I wasn't very clear when I asked my question. I need to calculate how long time a jar has been closed - that is the time between I did my jar gas measurements. For each jar I wish to get the time since it was last sampled - the difference between the start_date.time and the end_date.time from the previous time the jar was sampled. So for jar 1, the first difference I want is the difference between start_date.time in pf2.1 and end_date.time in pf1.1 e.g. 2019-01-09 10:29:19 - 2019-01-05 10:41:00 = 4 days, 11 minutes and 41 seconds.

Comment: The next time difference for jar 1 would be between pf3.1 start_date.time and pf2.1 end_date.time e.g 2019-01-15 10:11:52 - 2019-01-09 10:39:35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try the following `script` and use it as a base for your code. I don't have very clear what do you want to achieve.

```
convert_to_date <- function(string){
    # Tansform string -> datetime in order to compute difference
    as.POSIXct(string, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
}

make_delay_diff <- function(start, end){
    n <- length(start)
    arr_ <- c(0) # Starts with 0 diff

    for(i in 2:n) { # Starts at element 2
        time_diff <- difftime(start[i], end[i - 1], units = "day") # Compute diff in days

        # Set to 0 if have "negative" days
        val <- ifelse(as.numeric(time_diff) < 0, 0, round(time_diff,2))

        arr_ <- append(arr_, val) # Append value and save it
    }

    return(arr_)
}


data %>%
        # group_by(jar) %>%
        arrange(jar, campaign) %>%
        mutate(start_date.time = convert_to_date(start_date.time)) %>% 
        mutate(end_date.time = convert_to_date(end_date.time)) %>%
        mutate(time_diff = make_delay_diff(start_date.time, end_date.time))
```

Hope this can help you

Comment: Thanks for helping me out Victor! I guess I wasn't very clear when I asked my question. I need to calculate the time between gas measurements of soil incubations (jars). What your code provides is the time of the actual measurement. For each jar I wish to get the time difference between the start_date.time and the end_date.time from the previous time the jar was sampled. That's what I meant by nearest end_time that's < start_date.time.

Comment: @Magnus I've just edit the code according to your explanation, hope this is the answer that you've looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works very nice. I did arrange it according to (jar, start_date.time) instead of (jar, campaign) as R uses lexicographic sorting, resulting in pf10.1 coming before pf2.1 in the campaign column.